# How to install a tar.gz on Windows?

Tags: installation, tar

I have installed a MPD (Music Player Daemon) on my Raspberry Pi (running under Unix). Then GMPC (the client) on Windows. There is a plugin for the GMPC to catch the album covers, but it is a tar.gz archive. How can I install this?

I **can** extract the files. I don't have a problem with that. But when I extract the files from the archive, I get these files:

```
aclocal.m4
config.guess
config.h.in
config.sub
configure
configure.ac
COPYING
depcomp
instal-sh
Itmain.sh
Makefile.am
Makefile.in
missing
mkinstalldirs
```

What should I do with these files?

Comment: You could start by extracting the archive with 7zip

Comment: That's not a problem...I just don't know what to do with the extracted files

Answer (score 6):

In the general case, there is no "installation" with `.tar.gz` -- just like a `.zip` file, the archive can contain just about anything, including but not limited to backups of your photos, a collection of email messages, drawings for a CAD system, etc etc.

What you have downloaded is a source tarball.  The files in the archive are what a programmer would use to build a binary for their architecture.  This particular project looks very much like it was designed for Unix-compatible systems, and will not trivially build on Windows.

Projects which are portable to Windows will often contain something like a `Makefile.win32` (perhaps in a subdirectory) with basically a compilation recipe for the `make` utility, or a `proj` file for Visual Studio.

The generic Unix instructions for building from a tarball are basically

1. Extract the tarball.
2. Look for a file named `README` or similar. If you find one, it probably reiterates or supersedes the rest of these instructions.  The file could also be called `INSTALL`, though this is often a file with generic installation instructions which are not really specific to this particular project.
3. If there are files named something like `Makefile.am` you might need to be able to run `automake` to proceed.
4. If there is a file named `configure` which is executable, run that. It will try to figure out what components you need to install in order to be able to proceed. If it runs successfully, you can proceed to the next step.  If not, you need to understand why it failed, fix the problem, and goto 4.
5. If there is a file named something like `Makefile.yourplatform` (so `Makefile.linux` for Linux, `Makefile.BSD` for *BSD, `Makefile.suxix` for Suxix, etc) try running `make -f Makefile.yourplatform` where obviously the name of the Makefile needs to be the correct one from the ones you found.
6. Otherwise, if there is a file named `Makefile` (or perhaps `GNUmakefile` or `makefile`) run just `make`.  This performs the actual compilation using the compiler, libraries, and auxiliary toolchain utilities which `configure` picked up back in step 4.  If this fails, you have more work to do, probably way over your head unless you are familiar with writing portable programs in the language used in this project (commonly C or C++).

   An error message from `make` simply indicates that something that `make` tried to run did not succeed. If you need to ask for help, the lines immediately before the error message from `make` are more useful diagnostics than the final laconic "something failed" message from `make`.
7. Success.  There might now be an opportunity to run `make test` to check that the binary does what it's supposed to do, and/or `make install` to copy it to a system-wide location.

For reasonably modern projects, see if the site where you downloaded the source from would also have some instructions, and/or perhaps a collection of pre-built binaries for your platform.  Sometimes there are third-party contributed builds for godforsaken platforms even if the main development happens on and focuses on U*x or specifically Linux.

Answer (score 0):

- If you have a .arc file,  unarchive it with arc.
- If you have a .lha file,  unarchive it with lha.
- If you have a .rar file,  uncompress it with rar or winrar.
- If you have a .zip file,  uncompress it with rar or winrar, pkzip, winzip, ...
- If you have a **.gz** file, uncompress it with gunzip, winrar, 7 zip, winzip...
- If you have a **.tar** file, uncompress it with tar, winrar, winzip, 7 zip, ...

In your case you have a file which is first tarred and then gziped.

So use two programs in a sequence to get to the raw contents. Or use the same program twice. After that read the documentation. Most tarballs have a README file on the archive.